# JavaScript conditional statement only returns else value

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function PassTest() {
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    var message;    
    if (password == "apple") 
    {
        message = "OK";
    } else {
        message = "ERROR";
    }
    document.getElementById("PassTest").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="password"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit Password" onclick="PassTest()">
<p id="PassTest"></p>
```

The script should basically return OK if the password is equal to apple and return ERROR if the password does not equal apple. Although, when I run the script I get error regardless of the input.

Comment: it is supposed to be `password.value`, the property of button

Comment: `document.getElementById("password")` returns a _DOM element_ which you assign to the var _password_.  You then compare that DOM element to a String — they will never be equal.

Comment: I vote to close this question because it was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki This problem can be reproduced, and is not a typographical error.

Comment: Are you sure that the answer to this question can help future readers?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I've seen several questions by beginners here (*along students making the same mistake*) that have a similar problem with not getting `.value`. So yes, although it's likely there are a few duplicates somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do add `.value` to the element you receive from `document.getElementById`

```
  document.getElementById("password").value
```

```js
function check() {
  password = document.getElementById('password').value
  if (password == 'apple')
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'ok';
  else
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Not Ok'
}
```

```html
Enter you password
<input type=password id=password>
<button onclick=check()>check</button>
<div id=result>
```

Comment: You have no idea how relieved I am. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code works ok since in `password` variable you store the dom element, not its value. You can  test it adding a `console.log(password);`.

`var password = document.getElementById("password").value;` shoudl be the update you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("password")` will return a `[object HTMLInputElement]` whereas what you're after is the value of said input element. You need to access the value as in

```
document.getElementById("password").value
```